# Make: *** [] Error 1

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I've made a makefile and am trying to test it but am getting an error in make:

```
austins-macbook:work4 staffmember$ make new
rm -f main.o heap.o heap
gcc -Wall -O2   -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -Wall -O2   -c -o heap.o heap.c
heap.c: In function ‘createHeap’:
heap.c:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’
heap.c:6: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
heap.c:8: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘exit’
heap.c:8: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
gcc -Wall -O2 -o heap main.o heap.o
austins-macbook:work4 staffmember$ make test
./heap
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

I thought that getting make *** Error 1 meant that one of your components did not compile properly, however there weren't any error messages when I compiled it. How do I find out what the problem is?

Comment: While this doesn't have anything to do with your question, you might want to add the missing `#include`s to `heap.c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`./heap` probably returned a non-zero exit code, which `make` is interpreting as an error. Make sure you are doing `return 0;` at the end of `main`.

Comment: This is correct, I wasn't returning 0 at the end of main. Thanks!