# make:*** [Lab1] Error 1

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, binaries

I already read everything [Make: *** [] Error 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894675/make-error-1) and I am returning a 0 in my main method.

I've tried switching up parsers, but that doesn't work either.  I've tried the internal build, that doesn't work (and even if it did I want to work with makefile's).

Here's an example of the error being given.  I believe this is what's preventing me from creating the binary files which is a must have in order to run my app.

Error image link -> http://upit.cc/i/c6b2db81.png

Here's the console bit.  I did a refresh and then build.

```
23:52:19 **** Build of configuration Debug for project Lab1 ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/Run.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Run.d" -MT"src/Run.d" -o "src/Run.o" "../src/Run.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/Run.cpp

Building file: ../shared-src/EndToken.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"shared-src/EndToken.d" -MT"shared-src/EndToken.d" -o "shared-src/EndToken.o" "../shared-src/EndToken.cpp"
Finished building: ../shared-src/EndToken.cpp

Building file: ../shared-src/ErrorToken.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"shared-src/ErrorToken.d" -MT"shared-src/ErrorToken.d" -o "shared-src/ErrorToken.o" "../shared-src/ErrorToken.cpp"
Finished building: ../shared-src/ErrorToken.cpp

Building file: ../shared-src/Token.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"shared-src/Token.d" -MT"shared-src/Token.d" -o "shared-src/Token.o" "../shared-src/Token.cpp"
Finished building: ../shared-src/Token.cpp

Building file: ../server-src/server-token/SToken.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"server-src/server-token/SToken.d" -MT"server-src/server-token/SToken.d" -o "server-src/server-token/SToken.o" "../server-src/server-token/SToken.cpp"
Finished building: ../server-src/server-token/SToken.cpp

Building file: ../server-src/server-token/StartSToken.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"server-src/server-token/StartSToken.d" -MT"server-src/server-token/StartSToken.d" -o "server-src/server-token/StartSToken.o" "../server-src/server-token/StartSToken.cpp"
Finished building: ../server-src/server-token/StartSToken.cpp

Building file: ../server-src/Message.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"server-src/Message.d" -MT"server-src/Message.d" -o "server-src/Message.o" "../server-src/Message.cpp"
Finished building: ../server-src/Message.cpp

Building file: ../server-src/Server.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"server-src/Server.d" -MT"server-src/Server.d" -o "server-src/Server.o" "../server-src/Server.cpp"
Finished building: ../server-src/Server.cpp

Building file: ../server-src/User.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"server-src/User.d" -MT"server-src/User.d" -o "server-src/User.o" "../server-src/User.cpp"
Finished building: ../server-src/User.cpp

Building target: Lab1
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "Lab1"  ./src/Run.o  ./shared-src/EndToken.o ./shared-src/ErrorToken.o ./shared-src/Token.o  ./server-src/server-token/SToken.o ./server-src/server-token/StartSToken.o  ./server-src/Message.o ./server-src/Server.o ./server-src/User.o   
./shared-src/Token.o:(.rodata._ZTV5Token[_ZTV5Token]+0x20): undefined reference to `Token::getNextToken(char*)'
./shared-src/Token.o:(.rodata._ZTV5Token[_ZTV5Token]+0x28): undefined reference to `Token::processToken(char*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Lab1] Error 1
23:52:20 Build Finished (took 904ms)
```

As you can see from the image, Lab1 has no Binaries and it's showing the make error.

**Solution found thanks to guys commenting**

I'm including this code as reference to the comments to this question.

```
/*
 * Token.h
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 12, 2013
 *      Author: cam
 */
#pragma once

class Token {

public:
    Token();
    virtual ~Token();

    enum TOKEN_TYPE {START, MIDDLE, END, ERROR};
    /**
     * @pre processToken must be ran first!
     */
    virtual Token getNextToken(char*);
    virtual bool processToken(char*);

};
```

/*
 * Token.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 12, 2013
 *      Author: cam
 */

```
#include "Token.h"

Token::Token() {

}

Token::~Token() {

}

Token Token::getNextToken(char* buff) {

}

bool Token::processToken(char * buff) {

}
```

Comment: Please copy the text from the "Console" tab, and edit your question to include the *complete* and *unedited* error message. The one here just says that the build process failed, nothing more.

Comment: Hey, I've included the bit you asked.  Thanks, I'm very very new to c++.  When the error is simply stating my project name your suggesting I leave that in there?

Comment: What file are `Token::getNextToken(char*)` and `Token::processToken(char*)` implemented in?  Show us that code.

Comment: Okay so It's compiling now.  I added method definitions to the two methods you commented out above.  I want Token to be an abstract base class though, and both of those methods are virtual.  Is it necessary for me to define them?

Comment: Without seeing the applicable code it's hard to say.

Comment: I've added the code the original question.  Thanks for all the help too guys, I appreciate it.  I feel like an idiot not realizing the console printed more detailed information out, but then again this is my first dance with C++.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I wasn't including two virtual method definitions in my base class. While this got it to compile, I'm curious to know why this is necessary as they are defined as virtual.

Comment: `virtual` just means that if you use a base pointer to a subclass and call the function it will call the function in the subclass.  Since you mentioned making the class abstract what you probably want is a pure virtual function.